# Installing Tomcat-8 using Chef

Tags: java, tomcat, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to install Tomcat 8 using Chef with Terraform. Everything is working fine up to adding the Tomcat run list to the node. After getting logged into the client system, when I hit  `sudo chef-client` it gives me error which is attached below. The Tomcat and it's dependence are downloaded from Chef Supermarket. Please help me to resolve this. TIA[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi6SB.jpg)

Comment: I cannot believe you want to install openjdk-6, you want openjdk-8.

Answer (score 0):

From your attached exception you need to provide in recipe's `attributes/default.rb` openjdk_version attribute.

```
node['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
```

In that way you will override default 6 version of jdk. 
However I'm not entirely sure for the correct syntax here, you can try with that too:

```
default['java']['openjdk_version'] = 'openjdk-8-jdk'
```

For reference you can check https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java